# PhpStorm to warn on lack of 'require'

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Is there a way to make PhpStorm warn in some way when a class is being used that hasn't been 'required' in this particular file?

Comment: Nowadays when class autoloading is widely used (e.g. try to find any modern library/framework that is not using it) it's quite surprising to see such request. **In any case:** PhpStorm does not have such inspection for exactly the same reason -- wide usage of class autoloading. Keep in mind that *in general* lazy loading (autoloading) performance-wise is better than using require_once , especially in case of popular/frequently used class: the loading routine will be executed only once while require_once checks will be executed in every file where such class is used.

Comment: @LazyOne What exactly is class autoloading and how does it work?

Comment: Hmmm... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: 2) https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading 3) http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-composer-autoloading/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PhpStorm 9, you can set up and code inspection as far as I know. but I would recommend you to use [php code sniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) 
It's a common and powerful tool to keep your code clean and nice!
Also php code sniffer could be integrated in PhpStorm see here https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html